# PHP - Web scraping - How to cache using cURL?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I have a script which has a list of urls and I'm getting information from these url, like name, city, departament, etc

These are some of my functions:

```
function getCity($url)
    {
    $url = curl_get_contents($url);
    $html_object = str_get_html($url);
    return $ret = $html_object->find('td', 86)->plaintext;
    }

function getDepartment($url)
    {
    $url = curl_get_contents($url);
    $html_object = str_get_html($url);
    return $ret = $html_object->find('td', 90)->plaintext;
    }

function getSalary($url)
    {
    $url = curl_get_contents($url);
    $html_object = str_get_html($url);
    $ret = $html_object->find('td', 94)->plaintext;
    return trim($ret);
    }
```

and this is my cURL code:

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $curl_moteur = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  curl_setopt($curl_moteur,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $web = curl_exec($curl_moteur);
  curl_close($curl_moteur);
  return $web;
}
```

As you can see, I'm making a request for each field, which is very inefficient.
I would like to implement a cache in order to extract all the information fields requesting each url just one time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just save the $web return in a file, and open it at required time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class from your functions like so:

```
  class Scrapper
{
    public $page_content;

    public $html_object;

    public function __construct($url)
    {
        $this->page_content = $this->curl_get_contents($url); //in case you want to keep for something scrapped url content
        $this->html_object  = $this->str_get_html($this->page_content); //create object from html, probably simpleXML
    }

    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->html_object->find('td', 86)->plaintext;
    }

    public function getDepartment()
    {
        return $this->html_object->find('td', 90)->plaintext;
    }

    public function getSalary()
    {

        $ret = $this->html_object->find('td', 94)->plaintext;
        return trim($ret);
    }

    public function curl_get_contents($url)
    {
        $curl_moteur = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($curl_moteur,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

        curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $web = curl_exec($curl_moteur);
        curl_close($curl_moteur);
        return $web;
    }

    public function str_get_html()
    {
        //unkown function content
        $this->html_object = $some_object; // $some_object = str_get_html($url) from your code;
    }
}

$scrapper = new Scrapper($your_url);

echo $scrapper->getCity();
echo $scrapper->getDepartment();
```

Note that code is untested.

This way you request the url once when instantiate the class.

or if you don't want to use objects an easy fix would be to use [`static`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) variable:

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  static $web = null;
  if (!is_null($web)) {
     return $web;
  }

  $curl_moteur = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  curl_setopt($curl_moteur,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $web = curl_exec($curl_moteur);
  curl_close($curl_moteur);
  return $web;
}
```